# Inc and ld functions in AVR

Tags: assembly, avr

I have `yh(R29), yl(R28) = 0xFF, R16 is empty`

I have a question:
After `inc yl` we'll have `yl = 0x01` and flag z = 0 and flag c = 1 ?
And what will be in r16 after `ld r16,-y`

Comment: Why do you expect `0xFF + 1` to be `0x01`?

Comment: ok, it should be 0x100

Comment: `0x00` seems more plausible, given that `inc` operates on a single register and not a register pair.

Comment: `inc` doesn't modify flag `C`

Comment: ok, but what will be in `r16` after `ld r16,-y`